# How to detect if a key is pressed at C# Metro App?

Tags: c#, keyboard, microsoft-metro, keyboard-events, windows-store

I have a game that works with a loop frame.
For each loop, I need to know if any game key is pressed (Arrows/Crtl/Space).

I was using the Win32 dll to do this, it is very simple, but Metro App can`t use this DLL.

So I tried to use the `CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().GetKeyState`, but this is very bad (very bad)..

Then I tried to use the Canvas/MainPage Events KeyUp/KeyDown, but this events do not detect the control up/down, and I need this.

What other strategy can I use? Someone had the same challenge?

Thanks!!!

Comment: for detecting Control and space on `keyDown` event you can use `e.Modifiers == Keys.Control` and ...

Comment: @Mehran, it is not so simple. I can do this to know if Control is pressed when a key was pressed, I need to know if the `Ctrl` was pressed alone... At the `keyDown` event, when the user press the `Ctrl` alone, the event is not triggered.